# Jooq ARRAY_AGG where clause

Tags: scala, google-bigquery, jooq

I have query which I want to execute using scala Jooq arguments.

> select * from `table` where ("value1") in unnest(array) and ("value2") in unnest(array);

I can convert this part to below jooq arguments but i am not able to get what i need to do for where clause.

> dslContext.select(asterisk()).from(table).where(*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular syntax seems to be unsupported by jOOQ at the moment, see also this feature request:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12330

If you're ever missing a feature in jOOQ, you can always extend jOOQ via [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/). In this case:

```java
def inUnnest[T](value: T, array: Field[Array[T]]): Condition = 
  inUnnest(DSL.value(value), array)

def inUnnest[T](value: Field[T], array: Field[Array[T]]): Condition =
  DSL.condition("{0} in unnest ({1})", value, array)
```